# google translate not translating in R

Tags: r, google-translate

I have this data frame:

```
str(revision_vehicular_2017_08_01_)
```

> Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  1 obs. of  17 variables:
>
> ```
> $ X1           : int 1
> $ text         : chr "el plan operativo contempla una revision tecnica vehicular por parte de amtquito escuchanos por radio municipal t co ojrdm jo"
> $ favorited    : logi FALSE
> $ favoriteCount: int 3
> $ replyToSN    : chr NA
> $ created      : POSIXct, format: "2017-08-10 13:08:14"
> $ truncated    : logi FALSE
> $ replyToSID   : chr NA
> $ id           : num 8.96e+17
> $ replyToUID   : chr NA
> $ statusSource : chr "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"
> $ screenName   : chr "ObrasQuito"
> $ retweetCount : int 3
> $ isRetweet    : logi FALSE
> $ retweeted    : logi FALSE
> $ longitude    : chr NA
> $ latitude     : chr NA
> - attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
>  ..$ cols   :List of 17
>  .. ..$ X1           : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
>  .. ..$ text         : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ favorited    : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_logical" "collector"
>  .. ..$ favoriteCount: list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
>  .. ..$ replyToSN    : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ created      :List of 1
>  .. .. ..$ format: chr ""
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_datetime" "collector"
>  .. ..$ truncated    : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_logical" "collector"
>  .. ..$ replyToSID   : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ id           : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_double" "collector"
>  .. ..$ replyToUID   : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ statusSource : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ screenName   : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ retweetCount : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
>  .. ..$ isRetweet    : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_logical" "collector"
>  .. ..$ retweeted    : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_logical" "collector"
>  .. ..$ longitude    : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  .. ..$ latitude     : list()
>  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_character" "collector"
>  ..$ default: list()
>  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_guess" "collector"
>  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
> ```

I am trying to translate the column text form spanish to english. I have enabled an API as these link´s instructions https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=translate1-178522

```
google.dataset.out <- translate(dataset = df,
                                    content.field = 'text',
                                    google.api.key = "XXX",
                                    source.lang = 'es',
                                    target.lang = 'en')
```

When I ran the code the results are still in Spanish. The translation is not working.

When I downloaded the traffic from the last 7 days I see activity on the moment I tried to make the translation.

> tiempo    v2
>   31/8/2017 18:08   0.001666667